# What is this oscilloscope accessory?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I have access to a `FLUKE 190-504 SCOPEMETER` oscilloscope. The following picture shows one of its probes.

[image: Probe]

I don't know the circled accessory in the above picture. I looked for it on Fluke's website and found that its part number is `FLUKE-RS400`. The following links have more information about it.

- Website: https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/accessories/probes/fluke-rs400
- Datasheet: https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/accessories/probes/fluke-rs400/ds

However, I still don't understand

1. What is it called?
2. How is it useful?

If someone knows about it, please inform me.

Comment: It's ground spring, you need to remove clip to install it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's an attachment used when taking high frequency measurements. It minimizes the distance between the probe and ground. The little finger is your ground. Here is a similar attachment: https://probemaster.com/4983hg-high-frequency-ground/

Comment: But, in order for that to work, there needs to be a convenient return (GND) pad/trace/IC pin close to the point you need to probe.  This is so that you can make contact with the trace of interest and the return with one position of the probe.  If you have to connect a test lead to that GND finger to get to a return, you've just defeated the who purpose of that attachment.

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that if you want to make sensitive measurements (for example to measure MOSFET switching speeds) you want to minimize the ground path your probe requires.   The longer the ground path the more inductance (and other parasitic components) you will add into the measurement thus distorting what you want to measure.  So by using this spring clip you can reduce the path to ground your probe makes.